# How do I install spellcheck in Ubuntu Web Browser?

Tags: browser

I have problems with spellcheck not working and/or being enabled in Firefox and with Ubuntu Web Browser. I did not find any other posts with this topic.

Right now I am not concerned with Firefox, just Ubuntu, but an answer to Firefox would be appreciated.

Comment: what you mean by Ubuntu Web Browser?

Comment: 14.04 is introducing a Ubuntu Web Browser, AFAICT.

Comment: @DKBose - http://iloveubuntu.net/web-browser-app-implemented-default-ubuntu-1404

Comment: What version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

That should be easy!

Open System Settings (Top right button) --> Language support --> Add support for your language.

In Firefox switch spell check language by clicking left button on text box and select from list of languages.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to  [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/central/), besides the default spell checker that appears on input boxes, you can also get various spell checking extensions - e.g:

- [Spell Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/spell-checker)
- [Ginger - Grammer and Spell Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ginger-grammar-and-spell-ch)